# Shapes drawn on canvas moves too far when drag and drop event

Tags: drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

I am facing an issue when dragging a rectangle, if I moved it just a little than it will redrawn too far from the current new mouse position.
How do I correct the distance calculation?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="face-canvas" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

        <script type="module">
            (() => {
                let canvas = document.getElementById("face-canvas");
                canvas.height = 300;
                canvas.width = 300;
                let cnt = canvas.getContext("2d");

                let isDragging = false;
                let offsetX = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
                let offsetY = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                let startX = 0, startY = 0;
                let selectedObjIndex = 0;
                let drawn_obj = [];
                drawn_obj.push({...drawBox(20, 15, 50, 50, "#1df"), index: 1})
                drawn_obj.push({...drawBox(80, 40, 50, 50, "#a33"), index: 2})




                document.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) => onMouseDown(event));
                document.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => onMouseMove(event));
                document.addEventListener("mouseup", (event) => onMouseUp(event));


                function onMouseDown(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    startX = Math.abs(parseInt(event.clientX - offsetX));
                    startY = Math.abs(parseInt(event.clientY - offsetY));
                    selectedObjIndex = selectedObj(startX, startY);
                    if(selectedObjIndex > 0) {
                        isDragging = true;
                        console.log("ffffffff")
                    }
                }

                function onMouseMove(event) {
                    if(isDragging && selectedObjIndex > 0) {
                        let moveX = parseInt(event.clientX - offsetX);
                        let moveY = parseInt(event.clientY - offsetY);
                        let newX = parseInt(moveX - startX);
                        let newY = parseInt(moveY - startY);
                        drawn_obj[selectedObjIndex - 1].x += newX; 
                        drawn_obj[selectedObjIndex - 1].y += newY;
                        console.log("newX, newY", newX, newY)

                        redrawAll();
                    }
                }
                
                function onMouseUp() {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    isDragging = false;
                }

                function selectedObj(x, y) {
                    for(let i = 0; i < drawn_obj.length; ++i) {
                        if(x >= drawn_obj[i].x && x <= (drawn_obj[i].x + drawn_obj[i].w) && 
                            y >= drawn_obj[i].y && y <= (drawn_obj[i].y + drawn_obj[i].h)) {
                            return drawn_obj[i].index;
                        }
                    }

                    return 0;
                }

                function redrawAll() {
                    cnt.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    for(let i = 0; i < drawn_obj.length; ++i) {
                        drawBox(drawn_obj[i].x, drawn_obj[i].y, drawn_obj[i].w, drawn_obj[i].h, drawn_obj[i].color);
                    }
                }

                function drawBox(x, y, w, h, color) {
                    cnt.fillStyle = color;
                    cnt.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
                    return {x: x, y: y, w: w, h: h, color: color}
                }
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The obvious problem is using `+=`, you keep incrementing coordinates more and more with each move. That's why it accelerates off the canvas so quickly. You need just to use `=` and assign the mouse coordinates corrected to the offset of the point inside the object where it was originally clicked.

Comment: @tromgy It is working now, but now when I drag the shape from any position than the cursor will set to the corner of it during the drag process, how can I keep the cursor on the position that use clicked on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

1. In the top level function add two variables for the offset *inside* the object:

```
let objectOffsetX = 0;
let objectOffsetY = 0;
```

2. Calculate them when the click event is received:

```
function onMouseDown(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    startX = event.clientX - offsetX;
    startY = event.clientY - offsetY;

    selectedObjIndex = selectedObj(startX, startY);

    objectOffsetX = startX - drawn_obj[selectedObjIndex - 1].x;
    objectOffsetY = startY - drawn_obj[selectedObjIndex - 1].y;

    if(selectedObjIndex > 0) {
        isDragging = true;
        console.log("ffffffff")
    }
}
```

3. When the mouse moves calculate the new object position using the canvas offset and the object offset:

```
function onMouseMove(event) {
    if(isDragging && selectedObjIndex > 0) {
        let newX = event.clientX - offsetX - objectOffsetX;
        let newY = event.layerY - offsetY - objectOffsetY;
        drawn_obj[selectedObjIndex - 1].x = newX;
        drawn_obj[selectedObjIndex - 1].y = newY;
        console.log("newX, newY", newX, newY)

        redrawAll();
    }
}
```

You may notice that I simplified some code, you don't really need to use `parseInt`, you've already got everything as (integer) numbers, not strings.

You can see the whole thing working on [codepen](https://codepen.io/tromgy/pen/oNGXyLJ)

Comment: So basically I have two issues:
01) The `+=`, it was incrementing more and more on each move.
02) I have to calculate the shape offset in order to keep the mouse cursor when I move it.